# Converting DEM to PNG tiles maintaining the pixel values?

Tags: leaflet, png, gis, raster, tiles

I am a GIS user. My goal is to query raster layers (access to pixel values of a Digital Elevation Model, a Gravity Model, and others) in a Leaflet.js application that I am creating.

To that purpose, there is, among other solutions, the next leaflet plugin:

"leaflet-tilelayer-colorpicker" (https://github.com/frogcat/leaflet-tilelayer-colorpicker).

To implement that, I need to convert e.g my DEM (Geotiff, 32 float, 10m-resolution, 84345columns-70021 rows) into PNG tiles format. I know how (I use TileMill and then mb-util), but I am not sure if I am able to maintain the pixel values (elevations in meters) when transforming a raster in tiles. If this would be possible, could I have any indication?

Thanks

Comment: You might reach a more suitable audience on GIS StackExchange for such a very GIS oriented question. Make sure your question contains enough technical details about what you are trying to achieve and your context, compared to your audience.

Comment: On one hand: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200251/how-to-use-gdal2tiles-on-a-custom-tiff-image-recieved-from-providers-to-generate . On the other hand: an alternative solution is to implement a Leaflet plugin to query pixel values from a `L.ImageOverlay` instead of from a `L.TileLayer`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and links provided. I was testing with L.ImageOverlay instead of L.TileLayer but anyway it doesn't works for me (I have a DEM in Geotiff format) and in this case Leaflet doesn't accept Geotiff but JPG or PNG (as I have read…). So, anyway I am forced to convert my DEM file to another format and here is my problem. In order to avoid this process, I found the “leaflet.wms” plugin that allows to achieve more or less my objective through the “L.WMS.Source” class, accessing to the GetFeatureInfo of my layer. I continue studying. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Global mapper to convert the Dem geotiff to osm tiles. Then, you can successfully implement the leaflet-tilelayer-colorpicker plugin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank's for your contribution! It would be great if you could provide some example code for showing how to use the Global mapper to convert the Dem geotiff to osm tiles. Thanks!